# Page setup in rdlc

Tags: .net, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc

I am using rdlc file for reporting in my win-form application.
I set the `page size of report as 8.27*11.69 inches(A4)` And the body Size 8*3 inches.
But while printing a `blank page is coming in between two pages`.
If anybody knows about this issue please share me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the report properties you will see that there are report margins.

The total size of the report layout is the body size + report margin size which propably exceeds that of A4 in width.

Try reducing the report margins or report body size.